# Optimization by calculus

Tags: calculus, optimization

Two flagpoles are 5 meters apart. One pole is 4 meters tall, and the other is 3 meters tall. A peg is to be driven into the ground somewhere between them, and a wire is to be attached from the top of each flagpole to the peg. We want to minimize the total length of both wires.

Answer (score 2):

Let's choose the origin at the tallest pole. The peg is going to be at some distance $x$ from the origin. Then the length of the first wire is $\sqrt{4^2+x^2}$. The length of the second wire is $\sqrt{3^2+(5-x)^2}$. Sum them up, take the derivative with respect to $x$ and set it to $0$. Find the solution.

Comment: I think this would work if the height of the peg was 0, but this problem implies that the peg has a height.

Comment: I do not see anywhere implied that the peg has a height. A peg, by definition, is a **short** cylinder. Emphasis on short.Part of it is in the ground, so the part above ground is negligible. If it is given, say $h$, then just replace $4$ and $3$ in the above equation by $4-h$ and $3-h$.